# Why does Snowflake LAST_QUERY_ID returns NULL?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Given the following procedure

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE z()
RETURNS STRING NOT NULL
LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT
AS
$$

const what = snowflake.execute( {sqlText: "select $1 as value from values (1), (2), (3);"} )

return 'Hi There';
$$
;
```

If I run the 2 statements below

```
CALL z();

select * from table(result_scan(-2));
```

I get an error "SQL Error [709] [02000]: Statement 01912a0c-01c1-0574-0000-4de50036137e not found"

If I run the 2 statements below

```
CALL z();

SELECT LAST_QUERY_ID(), LAST_QUERY_ID(-1), LAST_QUERY_ID(-2);
```

It shows me that LAST_QUERY_ID() and LAST_QUERY_ID(-1) are identical but also that LAST_QUERY_ID(-2) returns NULL...

Any idea why it returns NULL rather than something that would allow me to retrieve the result of my query `"select $1 as value from values (1), (2), (3);"`?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It shows me that LAST_QUERY_ID() and LAST_QUERY_ID(-1) are identical but also that LAST_QUERY_ID(-2) returns NULL

It's expected to see the same query ID for LAST_QUERY_ID() and LAST_QUERY_ID(-1), because they are same (the default value for [LAST_QUERY_ID](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/functions/last_query_id.html) is "-1").

On the other hand, the LAST_QUERY_ID(-2) should not returns NULL, and the "select * from table(result_scan(-2))" query should not fail.

If you define the function with [CALLER](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/stored-procedures-usage.html#label-sp-session-variables-example) rights, you can see that the LAST_QUERY_ID(-2) returns the query ID and the "select * from table(result_scan(-2))" query works:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE z()
RETURNS STRING NOT NULL
LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT
EXECUTE AS CALLER
AS
$$

const what = snowflake.execute( {sqlText: "select $1 as value from values (1), (2), (3);"} )

return 'Hi There';
$$
;
```

As a workaround, you can use the history window to check the latest queries. You should be able to see your query (01912a0c-01c1-0574-0000-4de50036137e) in the history tab. You will notice that these queries are executed by same user, and in the same session. Therefore, there shouldn't be a restriction on listing these queries.

I am able to reproduce the issue on my test environment, and I will report the issue to the development team. If you have access to Snowflake support, it could be better to submit a support case regarding to this issue, so you can easily follow the process.

Comment: Interesting... But to me "EXECUTE AS CALLER" is the workaround and I don't understand why it has an impact...
I'll see if I can reach support.
Many thanks

Comment: If you do not have the "EXECUTE AS CALLER" then the procedure executes as the owner of the procedure.  If that isn't the same role as you, then you don't have permissions to see the results of the query.  That is why the EXECUTE AS CALLER is important in this case.

Comment: I will have to use "EXECUTE AS CALLER" because in real scenarios, my users won't be the procedure owner so thanks for this valuable information.

However, just out of curiosity, I understand it should work without in this case where I create the procedure and then try to use it myself in the same session... Looking forward to Snowflake's answer...

Answer (score 1):

For the record, here is the answer I got from Snowflake Support

*This is an expected behavior because of security limitation placed on purpose (queries from inside a SP do not have access to queries outside and vice versa).
We put a blanket limitation that the world of inside and outside such SPs should be separated. From one the "result" of a query from another cannot be accessed. 
Yes, If we declare the procedure with caller rights, everything (LAST_QUERY_ID and RESULT_SCAN) works fine in this case.
There is a discussion going on to implement this use-case when the owner and caller of an "owner's right" SP are the same, all this limitations should be lifted. But we cannot be sure about the timeline, I can link this case with that discussion so that we have this record.*

Sounds good to me :-)